# Convert double to float without Infinity

Tags: c#, types, floating-point, double

I'm converting double to float using ye old `float myFloat = (float)myDouble`.

This does however sometimes result in "Infinity", which is not good for the further processing I'm doing. I'm okay with loss as long as it is pointing in the general direction as the original number (the relative number 'strength' on all numbers I'm converting must be maintained).

How can I convert float to double and avoid Infinity?

Background:
I'm reading a bytestream from wav/mic, converting it to `float`, converting it to `double`, running it through FFT calculation (this is what requires `double`), and now I want it back to `float` (storing the data in 32-bit image container).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So if the value is greater than `float.MaxValue`, are you happy for it to just be `float.MaxValue`? That will effectively "clip" the values. If that's okay, it's reasonably easy:

```
float result = (float) input;
if (float.IsPositiveInfinity(result))
{
    result = float.MaxValue;
} else if (float.IsNegativeInfinity(result))
{
    result = float.MinValue;
}
```

Comment: No, the relative distance (%) between each number I'm converting must be preserved. Not sure if something like `(float)((float.MaxValue / double.MaxValue) * myDouble)` could work. But as I understand the decimal precision is dynamic, so that wouldn't work... right?

Comment: @Tedd: I suspect you'd lose an awful lot of information due to the way that floating point values are represented, yes. Can you find out the range of *actual* values before starting to do the processing?

Comment: Thanks. Rewrote the memory handling to use 64-bit storage so I could use `Double` throughout the app.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the .NET method `Convert.ToSingle()`. For example:

```
float newValue = Convert.ToSingle(value);
```

According to the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tosingle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Converts a specified value to a single-precision floating-point number.

**Update:**
Upon further review, `Convert.ToSingle(Double.MaxValue)` results in Infinity so you still have to check for infinity as done in Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If a calculation result of a calculation exceeds the range of the type you're storing it in, it will be necessary to do one of three things:

1. Throw an exception

   Return a "sentinel" value which indicates that there was a problem, and which will preferably be recognized as effectively invalidating any calculations where it appears

   Peg the result to some particular value (to which it would be pegged even it if it didn't exceed the range of your numeric type).  For example, one may have a sensor assembly with two time-averaged inputs X and Y, whose "value" is (X*X)/(Y*Y)-(Y*Y)/(X*X).  If the inputs are noisy, a low value on one input may be read as an exceptionally low value.  If the measurement will be used to control a feedback loop, and if the "actual" value won't exceed +/- 1000000.0, it may be better to peg the value to that range than to let the control loop see a totally wild computed reading (X or Y being the smallest possible non-zero value).

There are many applications where the third approach would be the right one.  In such situations, however, if it would make sense to peg the reading at a value of a million, then it shouldn't matter whether the computation results in a value of 1,000,001 or 1E+39 (floating-point +INF).  One should peg to a million in either case.

Comment: I like you answer; it would be nice to have an example of 2 and 3.

Comment: @ScottFoster1000: Conversion of out-of-range numbers to `float` generally results in behavior #2 (with the pegged values being called "positive infinity" and "negative infinity"), but conflicting operations on infinities (e.g. adding a positive and negative infinity to each other) may result in a sentinel value called NaN ("not a number").

Answer (score 0):

Use this Function

```
public static float DoubleToFloat(double dValue)
    {
        if (float.IsPositiveInfinity(Convert.ToSingle(dValue)))
        {
            return float.MaxValue;
        }
        if (float.IsNegativeInfinity(Convert.ToSingle(dValue)))
        {
            return float.MinValue;
        }
        return Convert.ToSingle(dValue);
    }
```