# Overflow error VBA

Tags: vba

I have this code below, and I'm getting an overflow error at the line: 
s = s + (x Mod 10) [first line in the Do Loop]
Why? I declared x and s to be of type Double. Adding two doubles, why is this not working?
Thanks for your help.

```
Public Sub bidon1()
    Dim i As Double, x As Double, s As Double, k As Byte, h As Byte
    Dim y(1 To 6) As Double

    For i = 1 To 1000000

        x = i ^ 3
        Do
            s = s + (x Mod 10)
            x = x \ 10
        Loop Until x = 0

        If s = x Then
            k = k + 1
            y(k) = x

            If y(6) > 0 Then

                For h = 1 To 6
                    Debug.Print y(h)
                Next
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This code seems obscure. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, I'm not an experienced coder. The Do Loop is supposed to add up the digits of a number.

Comment: What do you mean by "add up the digits of a number"? 123 => 1 + 2 + 3 = 6? If so, there are vastly easier ways to do that.

Comment: You are going to have problems summing the digits in `i^3`when `i= 999999`. (since it will round to 9.99997000003E+17). The only way to get the precision that you want is to use the decimal subtype of variants, and use repeated multiplication rather than exponentiation.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the VBA `mod` operator coerces its arguments to be integers (if they are not already so). It is this implicit coercion which is causing the overflow. See this question: [Mod with Doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23549947/4996248)

**On Edit:**
Based on your comments, you want to be able to add together the digits in a largish integer. The following function might help:

```
Function DigitSum(num As Variant) As Long
    'Takes a variant which represents an integer type
    'such as Integer, Long or Decimal
    'and returns the sum of its digits

    Dim sum As Long, i As Long, s As String

    s = CStr(num)

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        sum = sum + Val(Mid(s, i, 1))
    Next i
    DigitSum = sum

End Function
```

The following test sub shows how it *can* be used to correctly get the sum of the digits in 999999^3:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant
    Debug.Print "Naive approach: " & DigitSum(999999 ^ 3)

    y = CDec(999999)
    x = y * y * y
    Debug.Print "CDec approach: " & DigitSum(x)
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Naive approach: 63
CDec approach: 108
```

Since 999999^3 = 999997000002999999, only the second result is accurate. The first result is only the sum of the digits in the string representation of the double 999999^3 = 9.99997000003E+17

Comment: That's probably it. Thank you for your help!