# Truncate vector of doubles to single precision at maximum performance

Tags: c++, c++11

I am experimenting in a fluid dynamics code with reducing the precision of the floating point numbers in certain operations to test whether double precision is really necessary.

For that, I have written a truncate function, that reduces the precision of a double precision vector to single precision, without converting the data. This allows me to evaluate the accuracy of certain functions without having to convert the code to single precision. As these evaluations are computationally expensive, I aim to have a truncation function with the highest possible performance. I have tried the following, are there any ways to do increase the performance of the `truncate` function?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

void truncate(std::vector<double>& v)
{
    for (double& d : v)
    {
        float d_float = static_cast<float>(d);
        d = static_cast<double>(d_float);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0., 1.);

    const int n = 512*512*512;
    std::vector<double>v(n);

    for (double& d : v)
        d = dist(mt);

    std::cout << "Before: " << std::setprecision(15) << v[0] << std::endl;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    truncate(v);
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
    std::cout << "After:  " << std::setprecision(15) << v[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Duration in microseconds: " << duration.count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: I will edit the question. Before going to the (large) pain of making the precision of the code flexible, I want to test what the effects are of truncating the precision, to get an estimate of the accuracy loss. For that I have to repeat a few expensive simulations and therefore I want to have a truncation function that is fast.

Comment: @DmitriBudnikov. I know that, but before I go trough the pain of converting my entire code, I first want to know whether the loss of accuracy is acceptable. As the test cases I run to find that out are expensive, I want to make this truncation function as fast as possible.

Comment: @DmitriBudnikov He wants to do what you say, but he also wants to check if calculation on `float` have an impact on the results. And instead of changing code to work on `floats`, he wants to truncate `doubles` and compare results with calculations on `doubles`.

Comment: @DmitriBudnikov. This is part of the testing as well.

Comment: @chiel have you thought of recompiling your code with -Ddouble=float ? It's a blunt solution but perhaps a quick way of finding out.

Comment: @dascandy. The code uses Message Passing Interface, so those kind of solutions don't work for us.

Comment: "Math operations are cheaper on float than on double." - citation required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For absolute performance of the truncate function, you may need to do things manually; Assuming you have access to OpenMP and SSE intrinsics, take a look at the _mm_cvtpd_ps (converts 2 doubles to two floats) and _mm_cvtps_pd (converts back to doubles).

Something like:

```
double * vec; // aligned properly
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 512)
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
{
    _mm_store_pd(vec + i, _mm_cvtps_pd(_mm_cvtpd_ps(_mm_load_pd(vec + i))));
}
```

This is the kind of thing I would try; you can play a bit with the OpenMP options, the exact shape of the intrinsics (perhaps use AVX if you have it available), etc.

Edit: The AVX variant is just _mm256_cvtpd_ps and so on, if you can implement this suggestion, you can implement the AVX version as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to truncate doubles to floats fast, there's quicker (and hackier) ways to do that. Depending on what you already know or can assume of the numbers it can be faster or slower.

- Can you have float-scale denormals?
- Can you have zeroes?
- Can you have NaN's?
- Can there be numbers that on the float scale would be infinity?

For this solution I'll assume you can have zeroes, but no denormals, NaN's or infinities. In other words, I can mask off every bit that a float wouldn't have and get a close enough approximation:

```
for (double &d : doubles) { (*(uint64_t*)&d) &= 0xFFFF_FFFF_E000_0000; }
```

This keeps your sign bit and exponent, and 23 bits of mantissa. To be entirely accurate you would also need to clip the exponent - but it would either result in a denormal (which we assumed wouldn't happen) or an infinity (same).

Note that a solution that does inform your processor about the actual type may be better and more accurate. This is meant as an explanatory post to illustrate what the actual difference between a float and a double amounts to.

Comment: I don't think "number that on the float scale would be infinity" exist. The conversion from `double` to `float` has undefined behaviour if the value cannot be represented by the destination type.

Comment: @KerrekSB Floats can only go to 2^127, but doubles can go up to 2^1023. There's a large scale between those where a double would convert only into an infinity-float. C# at least does do this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640742/convert-double-to-float-without-infinity .

Comment: This is a question about C++. C++ would not convert in such a fashion, rather, it would have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KerrekSB Depends on how you read the standard. You can represent it as either FLOAT_MAX or as infinity, and in that case it allows it to be either: " If the source value is between two adjacent destination values, the result of the conversion
is an implementation-defined choice of either of those values".

Comment: This would work for my case. The values remain very far from the FLOAT_MAX. The double is only needed to maximize precision

Answer (score 0):

Did you considered using a multithreaded version of your truncation function ? Something like :

```
void truncate(std::vector<double>& v, const int n_threads = 1)
{
  if(n_threads <= 1) {
    for (double& d : v) {
      float d_float = static_cast<float>(d);
      d = static_cast<double>(d_float);
    }
  }
  else {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (size_t id = 0; id < n_threads; ++id) {
      auto threadFunc = [=,&v]() {
        size_t beg = id*v.size()/n_threads;
        size_t end = std::min(v.size(), (id+1)*v.size()/n_threads + (id == n_threads-1)*(v.size() % n_threads));
        for (size_t i=beg; i < end; ++i) {
          float d = static_cast<float>(v[i]);
          v[i] = static_cast<double>(d);
        }
      };
      threads.push_back(std::thread(threadFunc));
    }
  for (auto & t : threads) t.join();
  }
}
```

For large vectors the gain should be important if you can afford using many threads.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using the plain old typedef (I prefer the using alias of C++11) as `using myType = float` and then using `std::vector<myType>` for the variables you would like to be floats in the code? This will give a precise idea of the accuracy and the performance of your simulation as well.

Here propagating the use of `myType` takes some time, but it is worth it IMO, since you get to flip back to double, if you want. Also as pointed out by @steiner, using parallel constructs as much as possible will improve the performance as well.

Comment: This does not allow me to evaluate the different operators independently. Furthermore, I'd prefer the usage of templates then.

Comment: @Chiel Got it. You would want to follow Stefan Atev's answer and use the intrinsics then.